# How to enumerate chrome.contentSettings values

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to enumerate the setting entries for contentSettings?  Seems like a significant oversight.

For example, how can you enumerate entries that were set for chrome.contentSettings.javascript using chrome.contentSettings.javascript.set?

I know you can use chrome.contentSettings.get to read an exact one that was set, but that doesn't give you all of them.